# My game has a "restart game" button on the end screen which calls the StartGame() method. How do I avoid recursion and eventual stack overflow?

Tags: c#, recursion, menu, stack-overflow

MCVE is below. How do I avoid recursively calling StartGame() and DisplayEndScreen? One way is to loop over StartGame(), but this doesn't seem like an extensible solution, more of a hack. Another solution might be: when the user hits R to restart, return to the main menu and pass in the Enter key as input into the switch statement, somehow.

What's a good solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Menu: Press Enter to start the game >>");

            switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    StartGame();
                    break;

                    // Other Menu Items

            }
        }

        private static void StartGame()
        {
            // Do Game

            DisplayEndScreen();    // NB: This causes recursion! I don't want this.
        }

        private static void DisplayEndScreen()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game Over! Select an option >> \n\n" +
                "R:\tPlay again\n" +
                "M:\tReturn to Main Menu\n" +
                "Q:\tQuit");

            switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.R:
                    StartGame();    // NB: This causes recursion! I don't want this.
                    break;

                    // Other Menu Items

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want it, why do you have it? Why not try your solutions, and see if they work, instead of asking for opinions? If they don't work, ask why. Opinionated questions are off-topic here

Comment: Something about your approach seems off to me (although take this with a grain of salt - I'm no game dev). Something called `StartGame` doesn't seem like it should be calling `DisplayEndScreen`. Perhaps `StartGame` should return to `Main`? Then if `Main` handles the flow from start to end screen, you don't get the recursion problem and `StartGame` won't appear to do "too much".

Comment: @Frontear I don't want to implement my first solution because I don't think it's extensible. I don't know how to implement my second solution. But more importantly, I'm almost certain neither of them is good ways to tackle the problem. I'm not looking for just any hack, I want a proper solution. Surely that's not off-topic?

Comment: You want a solution that will be based on opinion. Devs will implement things differently, I'd personally create a `loop` or `tick` method with an `exitGame` boolean that would handle closing it, instead of your logic. *This is opinionated*, and not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @PianoTelope - If you remove the "What's the best solution?" part and focus more on the "how can I implement this without recursion" aspect, then I think your question would be perfectly valid. That's really the only place I see that could be interpreted as being opinion-based.

Comment: @CodeStranger Surely there's some useful middle ground between "I just want any hack that will solve this problem in this one case." and "I want the definitive solution." I'm an inexperienced programmer, and even less experienced on this site. I'm genuinely asking these questions with no malice: Is it bad to ask for non-hacky fixes? Are hack the only answers I can expect to receive on SO?

Comment: @PianoTelope - I don't get what you mean. 95% of the time there is no "definitive" or "best" solution. For any given problem there might be a dozen possible solutions that all work equally well. That's why asking for the "best" solution can cause questions to be closed on this site - it can cause arguments about various approaches and which are actually best (it's more complex than that, but I don't need to go into that here). It's not bad *at all* to ask for non-hacky fixes, and just because you're not asking for "best" doesn't mean everything will be hacky. In fact, hacky fixes rare-ish IMO.

Comment: @CodeStranger Thanks for the clarification and not taking it the wrong way! I think we are in agreement: I'm not looking for "the best solution"; I'm actually asking "What's the best solution that you can come up with?" Is there a better way to phrase that? If so, I'll change the question. Thanks!

Comment: @BrootsWaymb You're right! StartGame() is not the best method name for something that handles the whole game play, from the moment you hit "Enter" in the main menu until you hit "M" in the end screen. Perhaps it should just be called Game(). Either way, that is supposed to be the method that contains the entire game, including the end screen. The Main menu method shouldn't handle the Endscreen surely? I don't fully understand your proposed solution, so I'd be grateful if you could leave a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling StartGame() inside StartGame() causes the recursion. The way to avoid it is simply not calling a method inside of itself.

I think the name of the functions are a bit confusing for your program, are you sure 'StartGame' is correctly describing what the function is doing? It seems more likely to be the actual game (game()?) itself. If the name instead was something that tells you that the game is actually running (as it looks like its doing), calling it again would make less sense for you.

Considering running a game, most basic solutions usually looks like this:

```
    bool game = true;
    while(game)
    {
      //game running
      if(exit)
      {
        game = false;
      }
    }
```